# .NET Core + Service Fabric + Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

We have a integration with Autofac for our Service Fabric Services which pass a child scope to the SF Service of pre-existing registrations.

This works well for Owin-style API services as the Autofac integrations expect scopes:

```
// Configure Web API for self-host. 
public Startup(ILifetimeScope scope){
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ... 
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(scope);
    appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(scope);
    appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);`
}
```

Current implementation expects global Container defined in `Program` class. Instead of `ServiceRuntime.registerStatelessServiceAsync` we use `container.RegisterStatelessServiceAsync`. 
The main idea is to create Service from existing container. This solution provides ILifetimeScope for a Startup class.

When we switched to .NET Core to host our API services we came into an issue in that the Autofac Integration expects a Container Builder:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    ...     
    builder.Populate(services);
    //HACK - we save global Container as static in Program. 
    builder.Update(Program.RootContainer);
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(Program.RootContainer);
}
```

Right now we have a nasty hack which updates the original container.

But I feel like I want a new childscope here or something which allows me to register the DotNetServices onto of the registrations already made as part of the Service Fabric registered ones.

Comment: where does `_scope` come from in your first code sample? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: The question has been updated. Hope it makes more sense now.